# How to access django request using graphene mutation info

Tags: django, graphene-django

I get this error 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'request'

PS: snippet is a truncated. Error is coming from info.context.request

````
  class Arguments:
    input = ForgotPasswordInput()

  ok = graphene.Boolean()
  message = graphene.String()

  @staticmethod
  def mutate(root, info, input=None):
    try:
      user = User.objects.get(email=input.get('email'))
      current_site = get_current_site(info.context.request)```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here the **`info.context`** itself the ***request*** object. So, it should be as,

```
current_site = get_current_site(info.context)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```